# C# WCF service with enum types

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, enums

I know that this question has been here a few times, but none of the answers helped me.
I've got DLL library in C# which contains MyType.cs class  with only properties and enumerations.

Now I want to use it in WcfService. So I  add serialization attributes like this :

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Enum1))]
[KnownType(typeof(Enum2))]
public class MyType 
{
    [DataMember]
    public Enum1 Property1 {get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public Enum2 Property2 {get; set;}

}

[DataContract]
public enum Enum1 { [EnumMember] First = 0, [EnumMember] Second = 1};

[DataContract]
public enum Enum2 { [EnumMember] First = 0, [EnumMember] Second = 1};
```

Now I use it in my Wcf service like this :

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Enum1))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Enum2))]
public interface IService 
{
    [OperationContract(Name = "GetSomeValue")]
    bool GetSomeValue(Enum1 argument);

    [OperationContract(Name = "GetSomeValue2")]
    bool GetSomeValue2(out MyType outparameter);
}
```

When I run it i get exception that MyType has been not loaded in WCF Service. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What exception message do you have exactly?

Comment: In your real code enums defined correctly, is it? Because in your snippet they are not.

Comment: Also I can't see where MyType gets involved. Its not returned by the Service; it doesn't implement Service, where is it involved? Also, Interfaces by convention should have an I at the start of their names, so Servive should be IService. It makes it easier to gtalk about and understand code if you do that.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote this question in a hurry, now it is edited and should be right. I wrote just an example not my exact code, but its the same problem I have. MyType is also used there, but in some methods I need just these enums as argument. Again, sorry for mistakes in snippet :)

Comment: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'SomeNamespace.MyType' from assembly 'SomeNamespace, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Comment: Is that on the client or the server?

Comment: I try tu run WCF Test Client - service build correctly, but can't run this test client